# CSS: set border-color to parent's background-color

Tags: css, inheritance

assume the following snippet.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px dotted grey;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.parent:hover>.child {
  border-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Note that the child-div has a border which has the same color like the parent-div.
When hovering parent-div, its background-color changes while the border-color (actually I'm using -webkit-text-stroke) of the child-div changes to the same color.

Instead of setting the child's border-color manually, I actually want the child to always use its parent background-color.
This behaviour is easy to implement when both elements are using the same property by simply inheriting it. Is there any way to achive this behaviour using different properties?

Thanks

Comment: May I know the reason of using same `border-color` for child?

Comment: I'm trying to make font-awesome-icons a bit "smarter". It seems that the only way to achieve this is using a text-stroke with the background-color. Since the background-element changes its color on hover/focus, I need to change to stroke-color too.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `border-color: transparent`

```
.parent:hover > .child {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

This will allow you to change `background` of parent only without overriding child's `border-color` each time.

> Don't forget to set child's `background-clip` to `padding-box`
>   so that background covers only the content area excluding `border`.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid grey;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.parent:hover>.child {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work, unfortunately I'm actually not using border but _-webkit-text-stroke_. Using transparent causes the browser to show the text-color (where text is a font-awesome-icon)

Comment: @user3479074: You should actually make such things clearer in the question. It is always much better to create an "actual" example than a "similar" example.

Comment: +1 for the reminder to set `background-clip` to `padding-box`. That solved a problem that was baffling me. Thanks, Mohammad Usman!

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS custom properties aka variables - they are inherited by children and can be used for any property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Define them in parent, and then you can reuse them in parent and child class:

```css
.parent {
  --parent-mainfill: grey;
  --parent-hoverfill: darkcyan;
 
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: var(--parent-mainfill);
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px dotted var(--parent-mainfill);
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: var(--parent-hoverfill);
}

.parent:hover>.child {
  border-color: var(--parent-hoverfill);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```